# Looping GDB in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, file-geodatabase

I am new to PyQGIS.

I have a Geodatabase that contains feature classes.

I am trying to get those feature classes into PyQGIS but how do I loop a Geodatabase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access ESRI .GDB in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127292/access-esri-gdb-in-pyqgis)

Comment: In above answer they mentioned how access single feature class from gdb but i need to Iterate the gdb to get the feature class